# I want to return an array after sqlite3 db.all call in Node.js

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I have this async function called getData and it returns a datas array after db.all call. My problem here is that it doesn't wait until db.all gets done. It returns an empty array. Here's my code:

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose()
let db = new sqlite3.Database('./datas.sqlite')

async function getData() {
   let dataArray = []
   await db.all("SELECT * FROM pressure_data", [], (err, rows) => {
      rows.forEach(row => {
         dataArray.push({ "Name": row['Name'], "Pressure": row['Pressure']/100 })
      }
   })

   return dataArray
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises)

Comment: Your `.all` is callback-based, not Promise based